# How to abort execution in a local plug?

Tags: phoenix-framework

If I use a plug locally in a controller.

For example:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  plug :authenticate_user_by_api_key!

  def some_method(conn, params) do

  end

  defp authenticate_user_by_api_key!(conn, params) do
    # Authenticate 
    #How to permit execution or abort it?
  end
end
```

As I understand, `authenticate_user_by_api_key` will be called before any method, correct?

I need to allow or abort execution of called method, how would I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I understand, `authenticate_user_by_api_key` will be called before any method, correct?

Yes.

> I need to allow or abort execution of called method, how would I do so?

You can use `Plug.Conn.halt/1` to halt the execution of further plugs, including the function that was originally going to be called by the Phoenix Router. For valid authentication, you can just return the original `conn` and execution will continue.

(Note: the second argument to the plug function is the plug options, *not* Phoenix's `params`. To access `params` in the plug, you can use `conn.params`.)

```
defp authenticate_user_by_api_key!(conn, opts) do
  if some_condition_which_is_true_for_valid_key do
    conn
  else
    # you'll generally want to respond with something before halting execution
    conn
    |> put_status(400)
    |> text("invalid api key")
    |> halt
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! what about selective plugs, if I say `plug :validate_internal_servers_call, "some message" when action in [:my_action] `

then, how would the `my_action` signature looks like?

Comment: You don't need to change any signatures. The only thing the `when` does is call the plug only for the specific actions. If you mean how to access `"some message"`, then that will be passed to `opts`. I just edited my answer to clarify that the second argument to the plug function is _not_ `params` but plug's `opts`.